# I can not hold a session variable passing by get

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session-variables

Good afternoon, I hope you can help me with my code, and I have four hours searching and can not find the error, I'm doing an exchange, the variables are stored in a session, the problem is that `$discount` is being cleared every time I added, delete, delete or update the product, I would like to put off this variable remains active as the others.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vender</title>
 <style>
    body {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    table {
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    form {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    table {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//INICIAMOS SESION
session_start();

//CONECTAMOS A LA DB
require ("config/conectar.php");

//CALCULAMOS DESCUENTO
$descuento = $_GET[descuento];
$des = $total-(($total*$descuento)/100);
$porcentaje = $total - $des;

//RECUPERAMOS VALORES DE LA URL
$product_id = $_GET[codigo];     //ID DE PRODUCTO
$accion     = $_GET[accion]; //ACCION


//SI EL PRODUCTO NO EXISTE MOSTRAMOS UNA ALERTA
    if($product_id && !productExists($product_id)) {
        die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("El producto no existe!");window.location.href="index-sin-estilos.php";</script>');
    }

//DECIDIMOS QUE HAREMOS
switch($accion) {
    case "agregar":
        $_SESSION['venta'][$product_id]++; //SUMAMOS UNO 
    break;

    case "restar":
        $_SESSION['venta'][$product_id]--; //RESTAMOS UNO
        if($_SESSION['venta'][$product_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['venta'][$product_id]); //SI LA CANTIDAD LLEGA A CERO BORRAMOS PRODUCTO
    break;

    case "vaciar":
        unset($_SESSION['venta']); //DESTRUIMOS LA SESION Y BORRAMOS TODO 
    break;

    case "eliminar":
        unset($_SESSION['venta'][$product_id]); //BORRAMOS EL PRODUCTO SELECCIONADO
    break;

    case "idescuento":
        $_SESSION['venta'][$descuento]; //BORRAMOS EL PRODUCTO SELECCIONADO
    break;

}

//USAMOS SPRINTF PARA ASEGURARSE DE QUE $PRODUCT_ID SE INSERTA EN LA CONSULTA COMO UN NÚMERO - PARA EVITAR LA INYECCIÓN SQL
function productExists($product_id) {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE codigo = %d;",
                        $product_id); 
        return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > 0;
}
?>

<form action="index-sin-estilos.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="agregar">
 <input style="width:150px;" type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Codigo del producto" autocomplete="off" autofocus required>  
 <input type="submit" value="ENTER">
</form>

<form action="index-sin-estilos.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="idescuento">
 <input style="width:150px;" type="text" name="descuento" min="0" max="100" placeholder="0" value="<?php echo "$descuento"; ?>" autocomplete="off" required>  
 <input type="submit" value="ENTER">
</form>
<a style="float: right;" href="index-sin-estilos.php?accion=vaciar" onclick="return confirm('Estas seguro?');">Borrar todo</a>
<br>

<?php   

    if($_SESSION['venta']) {

        echo "<table>";
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td><b><center>Codigo</center></b></td>
            <td><b><center>Descripcion</center></b></td>
            <td><b><center>Precio</center></b></td>
            <td><b><center>Cantidad</center></b></td>
            <td><b><center>Importe</center></b></td>
        </tr>
    ';

            foreach($_SESSION['venta'] as $product_id => $quantity) {   

                $sql = sprintf("SELECT codigo, descripcion, venta FROM productos WHERE codigo = %d;",$product_id); 

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                    list($codigo, $descripcion, $venta) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                 //CALCULAMOS EL IMPORTE
                    $line_cost = $venta * $quantity;
                    //CALCULAMOS EL TOTAL
                    $total = $total + $line_cost;

                    //CALCULAMOS DESCUENTO
                    $descuento = $_GET[descuento];
                    $des = $total-(($total*$descuento)/100);
                    $porcentaje = $total - $des;

                    echo "<tr>";
                        //MOSTRAMOS LOS DATOS EN LA TABLA
                        echo "<td>$codigo</td>";
                        echo "<td>$descripcion</td>";
                        echo "<td align=right>$venta</td>";
                        echo "<td align=center>$quantity ( <a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?accion=restar&codigo=$product_id>-</a> / <a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?accion=agregar&codigo=$product_id>+</a> / <a href=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?accion=eliminar&codigo=$product_id>X</a>)</td>";
                        echo "<td align=right>$line_cost</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                }

            }

            echo "</table>";

            //MOSTRAMOS EL TOTAL
            echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td colspan=1 align=right><b>Sub-Total</b></td>";
                    echo "<td style='text-align: right;'><b>$total</b></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td colspan=1 align=right><b>Descuento ($descuento%)</b></td>";
                    echo "<td style='text-align: right;'><b>$porcentaje</b></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td colspan=1 align=right><b>Total</b></td>";
                    echo "<td style='text-align: right;'><b>$des</b></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";

    }else{
        //SI LA SESION ESTA VACIA MOSTRAMOS LO SIGUIENTE
        echo "AGREGA UN CODIGO PARA INICIAR";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much in advance for the help you can give me ... A big apology for using Spanish words in the code but I'm from Mexico.

In the video shown as another product to put the discount is deleted. That's what I want to avoid ... http://youtu.be/QfjA-cUVL3Y

Comment: where is your $discount? I don't see it any where in your code

Comment: @MikeA $discount = $descuento, sorry

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Chances are, you're outputting before header using `session_start();` in its present position. 9 times out of 10, that's the problem, and/or a contributing factor.

Comment: also these `$_GET[descuento]` - `$_GET[codigo]` - `$_GET[accion]` need to be quoted. Error reporting would have thrown you an error for those also.

Comment: In the video shown as another product to put the discount is deleted. That's what I want to avoid ... http://youtu.be/QfjA-cUVL3Y

Comment: plus, since you're using everything inside the same page, you must use either `isset()` or `!empty()`. Again, error reporting will throw you an undefined index notice. You're not checking for errors and assuming success right away.

Comment: No errors were reported.

Answer (score 3):

You should debug your code a little better and your issue may not be coming form the `$discounto` variable.

I think your formula for calculating the discount is incorrect.

try this code and see if this make a different. if it works I will explain.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vender</title>
 <style>
    body {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    table {
        width:100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    form {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    table {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//INICIAMOS SESION
session_start();

//CONECTAMOS A LA DB
require 'config/conectar.php';


$total = 1000;

//CALCULAMOS DESCUENTO
$descuento = floatval($_GET['descuento']);

//RECUPERAMOS VALORES DE LA URL
$product_id = intval($_GET['codigo']);      //ID DE PRODUCTO
$accion     = trim($_GET['accion']);        //ACCION


$porcentaje = $total - (( $total * $descuento ) /100 );


//SI EL PRODUCTO NO EXISTE MOSTRAMOS UNA ALERTA
    if($product_id && !productExists($product_id)) {
        die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("El producto no existe!");window.location.href="index-sin-estilos.php";</script>');
    }

//DECIDIMOS QUE HAREMOS
$currentVal = 0;
if(isset($_SESSION['venta'][$product_id])){
    $currentVal = intval($_SESSION['venta'][$product_id]);
}
switch($accion) {
    case "agregar":
        $_SESSION['venta'][$product_id] = $currentVal + 1; //SUMAMOS UNO 
    break;

    case "restar":
        $_SESSION['venta'][$product_id] = $currentVal - 1; //RESTAMOS UNO
        if($_SESSION['venta'][$product_id] == 0){
            unset($_SESSION['venta'][$product_id]); //SI LA CANTIDAD LLEGA A CERO BORRAMOS PRODUCTO
        }
    break;

    case "vaciar":
        unset($_SESSION['venta']); //DESTRUIMOS LA SESION Y BORRAMOS TODO 
    break;

    case "eliminar":
        unset($_SESSION['venta'][$product_id]); //BORRAMOS EL PRODUCTO SELECCIONADO
    break;

    case "idescuento":
        $_SESSION['venta'][$descuento]; //BORRAMOS EL PRODUCTO SELECCIONADO
    break;

}

//USAMOS SPRINTF PARA ASEGURARSE DE QUE $PRODUCT_ID SE INSERTA EN LA CONSULTA COMO UN NÚMERO - PARA EVITAR LA INYECCIÓN SQL
function productExists($product_id) {
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE codigo = %d;",
                        $product_id); 
        return mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql)) > 0;
}
?>

<form action="index-sin-estilos.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="agregar">
 <input style="width:150px;" type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Codigo del producto" autocomplete="off" autofocus required>  
 <input type="submit" value="ENTER">
</form>

<form action="index-sin-estilos.php" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="idescuento">
 <input style="width:150px;" type="text" name="descuento" min="0" max="100" placeholder="0" value="<?php echo "$descuento"; ?>" autocomplete="off" required>  
 <input type="submit" value="ENTER">
</form>
<a style="float: right;" href="index-sin-estilos.php?accion=vaciar" onclick="return confirm('Estas seguro?');">Borrar todo</a>
<br>

<?php   

    if(isset($_SESSION['venta']) ) {

        echo "<table>";
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td><b><center>Codigo</center></b></td>
            <td><b><center>Descripcion</center></b></td>
            <td><b><center>Precio</center></b></td>
            <td><b><center>Cantidad</center></b></td>
            <td><b><center>Importe</center></b></td>
        </tr>
    ';

            foreach($_SESSION['venta'] as $product_id => $quantity) {   

                $sql = sprintf("SELECT codigo, descripcion, venta FROM productos WHERE codigo = %d;",$product_id); 

                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                    list($codigo, $descripcion, $venta) = mysql_fetch_row($result);

                 //CALCULAMOS EL IMPORTE
                    $line_cost = $venta * $quantity;
                    //CALCULAMOS EL TOTAL
                    $total = $total + $line_cost;

                    //CALCULAMOS DESCUENTO
                    $descuento = $_GET[descuento];
                    $des = $total-(($total*$descuento)/100);
                    $porcentaje = $total - $des;

                    echo "<tr>";
                        //MOSTRAMOS LOS DATOS EN LA TABLA
                        echo "<td>$codigo</td>";
                        echo "<td>$descripcion</td>";
                        echo "<td align=\"right\">$venta</td>";
                        echo "<td align=\"center\">$quantity ( <a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?accion=restar&codigo=$product_id\">-</a> / <a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?accion=agregar&codigo=$product_id\">+</a> / <a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?accion=eliminar&codigo=$product_id\">X</a>)</td>";
                        echo "<td align=\"right\">$line_cost</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

                }

            }

            echo "</table>";

            //MOSTRAMOS EL TOTAL
            echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td colspan=1 align=right><b>Sub-Total</b></td>";
                    echo "<td style='text-align: right;'><b>$total</b></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td colspan=1 align=right><b>Descuento ($descuento %)</b></td>";
                    echo "<td style=\"text-align: right;\"><b>$porcentaje</b></td>";
                echo "</tr>";

                echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<td colspan="1" align="right"><b>Total</b></td>';
                    echo '<td style="text-align: right;"><b>'.$des.'</b></td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";

    }else{
        //SI LA SESION ESTA VACIA MOSTRAMOS LO SIGUIENTE
        echo "AGREGA UN CODIGO PARA INICIAR";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the video shown as another product to put the discount is deleted. That's what I want to avoid ... http://youtu.be/QfjA-cUVL3Y

Comment: I am testing your new code and does not work, you saw the video? While the sample is the problem that I have

Answer (score 1):

Just move the:

```
//INICIAMOS SESION
session_start();
```

to the top of the document as:

```
<?php
    //INICIAMOS SESION
    session_start();
?>
```

so your document should start with:

```
<?php
    //INICIAMOS SESION
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

Hope this help! :-D

Comment: Why would `session_start()` need to be on the very top?

Comment: @MikeA because, that would throw/cause an output before header warning

Comment: In the video shown as another product to put the discount is deleted. That's what I want to avoid ... http://youtu.be/QfjA-cUVL3Y

Comment: does not work, you saw the video? While the sample is the problem that I have

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as moving session_start() to the top of your document. It should be called before anything else happens on your page, any output or headers set.

Are you seeing warnings on this point in your error log?

Comment: And you try does not work, the problem is that apparently is not keeping within the same session "venta" which is not the case, but to spend another value GET value "descuento" disappears.

Comment: In the video shown as another product to put the discount is deleted. That's what I want to avoid ... http://youtu.be/QfjA-cUVL3Y

Comment: does not work, you saw the video? While the sample is the problem that I have